# URL Mod Rewriting

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using codeigniter for my website, and before theres always that index.php? on my every url or links, for example

```
mysite.com/index.php?/about
```

Google has indexed all of my urls with that index.php? and I want to remove it and redirect it without that. I am having a problem rewriting the URL and redirect it to `mysite.com/about` and this what i have tried so far

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

what happened is, it only removed the index.php, 
for example `mysite.com/index.php?/about` will turn to `mysite.com/?/about` I don't know how to remove that question mark,

I'm not good on mod_rewrite thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That question mark (?) after `+index\.php\` will prevent your rule on removing the index.php, especially if tried mysite.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this one.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/[a-z]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can improve the rules slightly.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} index\.php?\?.+
RewriteRule .*$ %{QUERY_STRING}? [R=301,L]
```

Essentially, you don't have to worry about the entire request line in `%{THE_REQUEST}`, which removes all the complicated regex. Also, the rule redirects to whatever is listed in `%{QUERY_STRING}`, and removes the query string.

I am not sure why you used `QSA` in the first place. I think that was part of the problem earlier. Just for an exercise, you can try removing `QSA` and see what happens.